# Custom TEdit with input restrictions

Tags: lazarus, fpc

What methods should `TEdit` descendant override in order to react to the `OnKeyPressed` event itself, instead of some external function?

For clarification: my `TEdit` have certain symbols that can be typed in, but not all.
The most simple solution is to define `OnKeyPressed` in the form code, but I want to have an object that takes care of it itself, not delegating it to the `TForm` descendant.

Comment: What do you mean "reacting to an event", event handlers are called from component code.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Well, normally Form that has the element has a procedure to handle this event. How do I make TEdit descendant handle it by itself instead?

Comment: For the windows control, DoKeyPress calls KeyPress which you can override. You can set character to #0 and decide if you want to fire the OnKeyPress event there.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz and how can I deal with onFocus and onLeave?

Comment: _and how can I deal with onFocus and onLeave?_ - `procedure DoEnter; virtual; procedure DoExit; virtual;`